# drupal on postgresql vs mysql vs mariadb

Tags: database

Anybody using PostgreSQL with Drupal? I know MySQL is preferred for Drupal but I have an existing PostgreSQL instance running on the server. I might as well use it rather than use more resources by running MySQL (MariaDB) unless there are major drawbacks in using PostgreSQL.

So, how does running Drupal on MySQL compare to Drupal on PostgreSQL?

Also, are there differences between running Drupal on Oracle's MySQL vs MariaDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The occasional issue you can hit, is that a contrib module is either just badly written because the author didn't know better, or, more rare, deliberately used mysql specific functionality for some reason, meaning that the module simply won't work on your site.

I've only had this on a single occasion though, and it caused issues during installation. A quick hack of the modules install file, and everything worked out well from there on.

It's unlikely to be much of an issue, and I'm myself running some personal things on postgresql just get familiar with it.

Drupal doesn't care if you use mysql or mariadb. They're the same thing to Drupal.